# Java regex is working in my system but not in the server

Tags: java, regex, string

The regular expression is

```
String regex = "^[\\p{IsHangul}\\p{IsDigit}]+";
```

And whenever i do

```
text.matches(regex);
```

It works fine in my system but not in some of the system.
I am not able to track the issue.

Thank you in advance.

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unknown character property name {Hangul} near index 13
^[\p{IsHangul}\p{IsDigit}]+
             ^
       at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1713)
       at java.util.regex.Pattern.charPropertyNodeFor(Pattern.java:2437)
       at java.util.regex.Pattern.family(Pattern.java:2412)
       at java.util.regex.Pattern.range(Pattern.java:2335)
       at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2268)
       at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:1818)
       at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1752)
       at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1460)
       at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1133)
       at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:823)
       at java.util.regex.Pattern.matches(Pattern.java:928)
       at java.lang.String.matches(String.java:2090)
       at com.mycompany.helper.ApplicationHelper.main(ApplicationHelper.java:200)
```

Comment: what is the error on other system?

Comment: Sorry, i have escaped { and } because for test. and "other system" means "different JVM".

Comment: the exception is "PatternSyntaxException"

Comment: if i validate it from "Pattern and Matcher" also same problem.

Comment: We need to see how you are using this regex in your other system. Post some example which reproduces your problem. Also posting stacktrace of thrown exception could be helpful with figuring out the problem.

Comment: Hi Pshemo, thanks. same regex will be using in the both the system and the text is "xyz007". In my system when i call "matches" method then it will return true. But when i run same program in my friend's system it thows "PatternSyntaxException" exception, it tells the entered expression is not correct.

Comment: Are there any details about why "*entered expression is not correct*" in thrown exception? Could it be that as stated in answer below `\\p{IsHangul}` could not be recognized because of lack of Unicode support?

Comment: Hi Pshemo, please check the question i have added details for exception

Comment: This stacktrace points to ``\`` before `{` which your regex doesn't have. Post stacktrace of exception thrown from regex you posted in this question (the one without ``\`` before `{`).

Comment: BTW if you want to write comment to someone you should add `@` before nick of this person. This way such person will get notification of your massage. So if you want to write massage for me try to write it in form `@Pshemo your massage ...`.

Comment: @Pshemo sure, thanks for the information. Because, i am new here. I will send you the exact stack trace.

Comment: @Pshemo, i have edited the question for you. please look in to it. thanks.

Comment: It seems that regex doesn't recognise `Hangul` [Unicode block](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#block). Can you check on which version of Java this code is run? You should be able to check it with `System.getProperty("java.version")`. If not just print result of `System.getProperties()` and see if you are able to find version of Java there.

Comment: @Pshemo Sure, thanks for your advice. i will check and come back to you.

Comment: @Pshemo, the java version is 1.6.0_45. from System.getProperty("java.version"). thanks.

Comment: It seems that this version also doesn't support this Unicode block. If it is possible try updating Java to something newer like Java 7 or maybe even Java 8. You can decide to update to same version which you are using and which handles this regex correctly.

Comment: @Pshemo, you are right. in my system its 1.7 and its working. but in my friend's system its 1.6 that's why its not working. is there any way to to same in java 1.6 like {IsHangul}, any other way ? need help Pshemo.

Comment: Take a look at my answer. For now I can't think of anything better (beside updating Java on your other system).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Java version you are using is not able to recognise Hangul as correct [script character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#usc) so you can try to create your own character class which will cover same range as Hongul from newer versions of Java.

From what I see in code in source code of `Character.UnicodeScript` on Java 8 Hangul refers to Unicode ranges

- `1100..11FF`
- `302E..302F`
- `3131..318F`
- `3200..321F`
- `3260..327E`
- `A960..A97F`
- `AC00..D7FB`
- `FFA0..FFDF`

so maybe try with such pattern

```
Pattern.compile("^["
        + "\u1100-\u11FF"
        + "\u302E-\u302F"
        + "\u3131-\u318F"
        + "\u3200-\u321F"
        + "\u3260-\u327E"
        + "\uA960-\uA97F"
        + "\uAC00-\uD7FB"
        + "\uFFA0-\uFFDF"
        + "\\p{IsDigit}]+");
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [Using Regular Expressions in Java](http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html):

> **Java 5** fixes some bugs and adds support for **Unicode blocks**. ...

Make sure you're using Java 5+ in the server.

Comment: any way thanks. but the "IsHangul" will only work from java 1.7. Thank You.